# Междометия: нужен ли дефис?

Tags: орфография

Речь о междометиях типа "ай(-)ай(-)ай", "о(-)го(-)го" и т.д. Нужны ли в них дефисы или все они пишутся одним словом?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Дефисы нужны, так как происходит повтор междометий!  Ай-ай-ай, ой-ой-ой, ого-го (о-го-го - разные варианты в разных источниках), ей-ей и т.д.